# Do I need to track .gitmodules file in git?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-clone

Do I need to add or track `.gitmodules`? Or it is already being tracked internally by git?

I don't want to lose submodules when I make a new clone.

Usually my `git status` look like this:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitmodules
```

Comment: Have you considered making a clone and see what the behavior is? =) Probably faster than asking a question here. You can clone directories from your own filesystem, so you don't even need to upload anything anywhere

Comment: Yes, you should add and commit any updates to `.gitmodules`. These are the instructions that some *other* Git repository needs in order to clone the submodules.